# Delete automatic generated section- and subsectionslides in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, titles, slideshow, subsection

I'm using the focus-beamer-theme and whenever I start a new section or subsection, it automatically inserts a slides with the title of the new section on it. Is there a way to delete these pages / not generate them automatically? Didn't find anything online.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\title{example presentation}

\usetheme{focus}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{table of contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{1. section}
    
    \begin{frame}{1.section}
        This is an example
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You don't need the `graphicx`, `amsmath` or `xcolor` packages, beamer loads them for you. You also don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` -- that's the default since a couple of years .

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid (sub)section pages like this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{focus}

\AtBeginSection[]{}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{}

\begin{document}
    
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what i needed :D

Comment: @Fabian You're welcome!